# Copy multiple Web Contents and folders in Liferay Back Office

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I am looking for a way to do the following operations:

- select multiple web contents and copy them
- copy a folder (and its contents)

The interface does not allow to do neither of these, you can only move folders, copy a single file and move multiple files.

Is there a way to customize Liferay back-office and introduce these operations?

Answer (score 0):

to add new features to Liferay you have several possibilities.

I think the most suitable in you case are:

1. to customize Liferay behaviour directly by ext-environment
2. to write your own backend portlet

The first option has, without any doubt, the benefit to result invisible for users, because you are modifying the aspect of native portlets.
By the way this is more expensive in terms of developing time, if compared with the latter.

The second option can be devolped in a shortest time than the previous... but users need to go to different places for using document library: one for "standard" operation and "another one" (your portlet) for these custom operation.
Following my experience, this is not a real issue, because non-technical people is more insterested to perform an action than to find it in the right place... :)
Obviously this solution requires you to rewrite (/copy) some basic part of the Liferay code for managing default behaviour (e.g. to browse document library).
Another option fot this solution is to not provide to users the same Liferay user interface, but to write your one semplified version (e.g. to browse folder and to click on "duplicate" without any other options).

It's your choice.

Just, in the second case, don't forget to use the new (6.2) Liferay Document Library API.

Comment: There is a third option: use a hook. Always consider to create a hook first, before even thinking of an ext-environment. You can only deploy one ext-environment per Liferay instance and it is difficult to un/redeploy. But you can have more than one hook and un/redeploying is as easy as every other plugin.

Comment: You're right, thank you... I avoid to suggest it because to achieve what is needed, you have to write an hook that is: JSP hook, Struts action hooks and, to work in a proper way, a Service hook... and (in my mind) this is not the simplest way to proceed for who don't know LR architecture...

Comment: So you think that an ext-environment is simpler for someone who doesn't know the LR architecture :-) ? Besides this I would call it just _one_ hook with multiple _overrides_.

Comment: I just think that copy-paste code (and adding what is missing) is simplier than create from scratch one hook plugin (containing three different kind of hooks)... :)

Comment: Even for an ext-environment you should not just copy and paste files, but try to extend / wrap existing code into your own files. Otherwise every upgrade is a pain. My rule of thumb:
If it is a new feature: Use a hook.
If it is a bug: Use the ext-environment (and hope that you can remove that part in the upgrade).

Comment: Your rule is great, but several cases where is not possible to use hooks to override (or to use ext only by extending) exist...

Comment: Off topic - as the original question is a typical hook.

Comment: No... I would not use an hook for what is asked... so I don't suggested an hook... and may be wrong, but this is my answer! If you pefer another approach you are free to add a comment (or better a reply), as well I'm free to explain why "I" don't suggested an hook! At the end, my last comment is a reply to your one... you exposed your golden rule (out of topic because, I repeat, I would't use an hook for this... and don't forget I explained why it is not a generally valid rule): my oot is just a reply to your oot... nothing else... :)